# white line appearing when using border radius

Tags: css

I've got an input box when I apply border-radius to it there is a white space between the input-box and border.

Not sure why it is appearing. Please help

Note: i'm using bootstrap 3

[image: Image description here]

```css
.form-control {
  padding: 0 8px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid #1d79d1;
  color: #1d79d1;
  min-width: 96px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  background-color: #1d79d1;
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control filter-button selectedBorder">
```

Comment: What browser are you seeing this issue? It's fine for me (chrome)

Comment: i'm using chrome browser

Comment: Welcome to subpixels and rendering problems... You'll only find some small hacks to workaround this kind of stuff... I think i've found something in the past, i'll be back if i found anything!

Comment: Is your browser zoomed in?

Comment: yeah, i've zoomed in so that the issue will be more clear

Comment: everything is working fine in this bit of code.

Comment: Also not seeing the white line. Maybe something
    `box-sizing: border-box;` can fix?

Comment: I don't see any white line in chrome after zooming 200% also. Everything is just fine in your code. Added some `value` in your `input` tag and aligned the text in center. After that zoomed 400%. Just nothing I could reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

remove Borders as you're giving same colors to both border and

Comment: this might be a good answer to the question. However in order to give a great answer you could elaborate a little more.

Answer (score 0):

As your border color and background color are the same: Remove border and increase height or padding to compensate for height of border.

```
  .form-control {
  padding: 0 8px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #1d79d1;
  min-width: 96px;
  height: 34px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  background-color: #1d79d1;
}
```

I had similar issues. The input field and submit type can have rendering issues with border and border-radius feathering the border and background color.

Answer (score 0):

You can us a box shadow to achieve the same effect.

```css
.form-control {
  padding: 0 8px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  
  /* Change This */
  /* border: 2px solid #1d79d1; */
  border: none;
  
  /* Add This */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #1d79d1;
  
  color: #1d79d1;
  min-width: 96px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  background-color: #1d79d1;
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control filter-button selectedBorder">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).